# Many to Many Relationship + Google Datastore + Python

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Given the log of following:

```
Restaurant = <persistence.model.Restaurant object at 0x3913c01e89e78a20>
Review Content = This is my first comment...
User[0] = <persistence.model.User object at 0x3913c01e89e780a0>
```

and following codes:

```
class RestaurantReview(db.Model):
    owned_by = db.ReferenceProperty(Restaurant, required=True, collection_name='restaurant')
    written_by = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True, collection_name='user')
    content = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

When I was trying to create the instance of RestaurantReview, it just never work:

```
RestaurantReview(owned_by=restaurant, written_by=user[0], content=restaurant_review_content.__str__()).put()
```

EDIT
Any idea what's happening? It keeps throwing the custom error that I set.

```
try:

        RestaurantReview(owned_by=restaurant, written_by=user[0], content=restaurant_review_content.__str__()).put()
    except:
        logging.error('CUSTOM ERROR: Review for restaurant has not been added')
```

Comment: @bpgergo, I've edited in the last section. My own display error.

Comment: Sir MrCool, I still do not get what is the error.

Comment: I meant I'm getting the custom error from logging.error('CUSTOM ERROR: Review for restaurant has not been added')

which means the instance has not been able to be created from the try and except block?

Comment: a bare `except:` that catches everything is almost never a good idea, and definitely isn't a good idea for debugging. Without knowing the actual exception that's being raised, it's impossible to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: Yeah I get it. You should rethrow the exception in order to get a clue what could be the error.

Comment: (although I suspect that calling an object's `.__str__()` method directly isn't what you wanted to do here, and may indeed be what's raising the exception)

Comment: @Wooble, I'm aware of that and which was why I was asking suggestion for better error capture in python as I'm very new to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to rethrow the error by calling *raise*

```
try:
    RestaurantReview(owned_by=restaurant, written_by=user[0], content=restaurant_review_content.__str__()).put()
except:
    logging.error('CUSTOM ERROR: Review for restaurant has not been added')
    raise
```

Comment: Thanks @bpgergo ! By having the raise, I could see better error results returned which is a careless mistake of not declaring the object.

Hope you don't mind to answer my another question, is there a need to use the db.ListProperty(db.Key) ??? I read the documentation but wasn't clear about it.